# Loading react component dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react and i have an idea of an app. Basically, i would like in the main app to load react components from secondary apps. Here is an example:

1. Main server - Main App
2. Server 1 - App 1
3. Server 2 - App 2

If i go in the Main App i have 2 options: load App1 and load App2. If i click on App1, the Main App will request Server 1 for the js code for App 1. It will load this and then add the App 1 components.

I have already managed to do something like this. I have used create-react-app to create the Main App and App1. From Main App i do an ajax request for the App 1 js file and load it with eval. It will bind automatically to a predefined element id.

My goal is to be able to pass some params to the App 1 component, like, for example, the element id where to load it.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter from one component to another using props for example

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara" />;
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

it will render: **Hello Sara**

Comment: Thank you. I'm not trying to pass parameters inside the same react app. My main app just gets a webpacked js from the secondary apps. I should not know what's inside this js. I just want to pass a parameter and display the received js. For example, if the js contains a chart, i would like to pass the labels for the axis as params. I have just managed to do this following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521660/passing-a-value-to-bundled-react-js-file. But i hope there is a nicer way to do this with react, without having to use eval. Maybe do the apps as react libs?

Comment: well than just pass your parameter like that ` <Component {...this.props}/>`